# Limiting datagrid items using a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, converters

In my application the user can select a large amount of entities and I generate a `DataGrid` that is bound to the selection. As that amount can be thousands and it would hit the performance I am only interested in show a few, say 20.
The entities could be of several types, but they all derive from a class called `Card`.

In my SelectionView I have something like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridGrids" dgx:DataGridFilter.IsAutoFilterEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource DataGridSelection}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding GridsSelected, IsAsync=True, Converter={local:LimitItemsConverter}}">
```

And my current converter checks manually the type of the items in that collection and them takes only 20:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (value == null) { return null; }

   List<Element> elements = value as List<Element>;
   List<Grid> grids = value as List<Grid>;
   List<Prop> props = value as List<Prop>;
   List<Mat> mats = value as List<Mat>;

   bool listElements = elementos != null && elementos.Any();
   bool listGrids = grids != null && grids.Any();
   bool listProps = props != null && props.Any();
   bool listMats = mats != null && mats.Any();

   int num = 20;
   if (listElements )
   {
         if (elements.Count <= num)
         {
            return elements;
         }
         else
         {
            return elementos.Take(num).ToList();
         }
   }

   if (listGrids)
   {
         if (grids.Count <= numero)
         {
            return grids;
         }
         else
         {
            return grids.Take(num).ToList();
         }
   }
   //and so on
}
```

And that for each of the derived class from `Card`. I want to condense this a little saying something like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (value == null) { return null; }

   List<Card> cards = value as List<Card>;
   bool listCards = cards != null && cards.Any();

   int num = 20;
   if (listCards )
   {
         if (cards.Count <= num)
         {
            return cards;
         }
         else
         {
            return cards.Take(num).ToList();
         }
   }
   return new List<Card>();
}
```

But my lists are not being casted in `List<Card> cards = value as List<Card>;` statement and I'm not sure how could I tell my computer to do so.

Comment: how come you are not using the `List<Card> cards = new List<Cards>();` convention I am not sure why you are Casting or attempting to Cast here can you elaborate more on what your true intentions are here..?

Comment: The datagrid source can have 20.000 items: more than 10 seconds to generate the view. I want it to have only the first 20, so the selection is done much faster.

Comment: I am not sure but here you may be interested in using Virtual Panels for e.g. VirtualStackPanel, So, that it does not affect the performance and you can be able to show all the data to user.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to upcast and downcast collections of objects like that, you would need to enumerate and cast each item separately.

```
object tempobj = new List<object>() {"jack", "cat", "hat"};
List<string> tempstring = tempobj as List<string>;
```

in this case tempstring would be null.

DataGrid does support inbuilt UI virtualization, implementing your own data virtualization is going to be challenging!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ea28468-5505-4e28-8220-e216b77ecf28/wpf-datagrid-and-virtualization

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
  public class LimitItemsConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{

    public LimitItemsConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) { return null; }

        int max = 20;

        if (value.GetType().IsGenericType && value is IList)
        {

            var list = ((IList)value);
            Type type = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

            Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            var reducedList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);

            int min = Math.Min(max, list.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < min; i++)
            {
                reducedList.Add(list[i]);
            }
            return reducedList;
        }

        return null;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the type of the objects in the list and then create a temporal list where I only retain 20 items. I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks